# How to Define the UsedRange?

Tags: excel, vba, count, range, rows

I need to determine how many rows have data within "B6:B".

I'd like to avoid using the xlDown options.

The UsedRange function might work since it would tell me how many rows have data. Is it possible to restrict the UsedRange to a certain range?

Edit: I was able to use the "CountA" function to get the outcome I need.
I'm still curious if there are ways to specifically define what range the UsedRange uses.

Comment: You want to count the number of occupied cells in the whole of ColB starting at row 6?  `Application.CountA(Range("B6:B" & rows.count))`

Comment: @TimWilliams this is exactly the solve I needed! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an UDF for this:

```
Function TOTAL_NO_BLANK_CELLS(ByVal vRng As Range) As Double
TOTAL_NO_BLANK_CELLS = vRng.Cells.Count - vRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
End Function
```

You can execute it like this:

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print TOTAL_NO_BLANK_CELLS(Range("B6:B15"))
End Sub
```

It will return the total **non empty** cells in specified range.

**NOTE:** A formula returning value `""` will be count as **non empty** because it contains a formula.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I found a great alternative but I will keep this in my back pocket as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Tim Williams for this answer. This was exactly what I needed! Below is how I used the code:

```
    Dim Used_Contact_Rows As Long
    Used_Contact_Rows = Application.CountA(Range("B6:B" & Rows.Count))
```